# ReactJS : Using function as props to return value for <td> gives <Component/> error

Tags: reactjs, state

I have the following function:

```
budgetList() {
    return this.state.projects.map(currentproject=> {
      return <Budget project={currentproject} filter= {this.filterIssues} key={currentproject._id} stop={this.stopPropagation}  modal={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}/>;
    })
}
```

My issue comes from the `filterIssues` function which is used to filter through the state and retrieve some values. Posted below.

```
filterIssues (id, sprint) {

  let filteredIssues = this.state.jiras
                            .filter( issue => issue.fields.project.key === id )
                            .filter( issue => issue.fields.sprint.name === sprint )

  let sum = 0;                          
  for (var i = 0; i < filteredIssues.length; i++) {
      sum += filteredIssues[i].fields.timetracking.originalEstimateSeconds
  }

  sum /= 3600;
  console.log(sum)
  return sum;
}
```

Now I am using the function to retrieve a value for each  in the Budget element like so.

```
const Budget = props => (
    <tr onClick={() => props.toggle(props.project._id)}>
      <td>£{((props.project.proposedBudget / 4) *1000) }</td>
      <td>{() => props.filter(props.project.project, "APP" + 74)}</td>
      <td>{() => props.filter(props.project.project, "APP" + 75)}</td>
    </tr>
  )
```

The problem is that for every

> Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you
>   return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you
>   meant to call this function rather than return it.

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. Function works fine on its own outside the Budget component.

Comment: If you want to render the `sum` returned by your filter function, you should execute it. `<td> {props.filter(props.project.project, "APP" + 74)}</td>`

Comment: That worked thanks :)